# Запуск сервер realm

Tags: node.js, realm, nodemon

Пытаюсь запустить сервер 
https://github.com/nhancv/nc-graphql-realm

В ответ ошибки, в чем может быть проблема?

```
MacBook-Pro:server user$ sudo nodemon
[nodemon] 1.18.5
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: /Users/user/Downloads/nc-graphql-realm-master/server/src/**/*
[nodemon] starting `npm run build`

> treact-template@1.0.0 build /Users/user/Downloads/nc-graphql-realm-master/server
> ts-node --inspect=9229 src/index.ts

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/user/node_modules/realm/compiled/node-v64_darwin_x64/realm.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/node_modules/realm/lib/index.js:102:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! treact-template@1.0.0 build: `ts-node --inspect=9229 src/index.ts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the treact-template@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2018-11-02T22_27_41_238Z-debug.log
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из Вашей ошибки, у Вас не установлен модуль `realm`. Установите его с помощью пакетного менеджера командой `npm i realm`.